# Gulp sass failing silently

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a very simple gulp task for transforming scss into css files:

```
function css() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/_index.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
}
```

As you probably imagine, `_index.scss` mostly imports other files.

Now, if I comment out line number 3, the code does what it's supposed to: it copies `_index.scss` to `public/css`. But with line 3 it produces no output whatsoever, without printing any errors to the console. All I get is:

```
[0] [17:32:46] Starting 'css'...
[0] [17:32:46] Finished 'css' after 79 ms
```

How can I even inspect what might be an issue here? The sass file is correct, as before that I would compile it without using gulp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `_index.scss` to `index.scss`. Sass interprets underscore-prefixed files as partials, and won't output them directly. https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I have no idea how I missed it - though it was working before! Thank you so much!